# Is there any way to check a image size before uploading in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-native, image-upload

I am currently using image picker and image manipulator in my project for uploading and compressing the image. But I want to show user that he cannot upload image greater than any particular size(let's say 5mb). How can I achieve this in react- native?

Comment: On the client side, you could use the javascript FileReader object.  Upon reading a file with that, you can then interrogate the result to determine the length (in bytes).  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually doing this exact thing with ImagePicker in my app. Here's how I do it:

```
const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: "Images",
    allowsEditing: true,
    base64: true,
    quality: 1,
});

if (!result.cancelled) {
    const fileSize = result.base64.length * (3 / 4) - 2;
    if (fileSize > 6000000) {
        setFileSizeError(true);
    } else {
        setFileSizeError(false);
        const base64 = `data:image/png;base64,${result.base64}`;
        await dispatch(myExampleAction(base64));
    }
}
```

File size is calculated by the function `-your base64 string length- * (3 / 4) - 2`. Where at the end `- 2` depends on how many `==` your base64 is trailed by. For example just one `=` would be `- 1` instead.

Also `fileSizeError` is set by `setFileSizeError`. And will switch the boolean if it's bigger than 6000000 bytes.